# How to workaround readObject similar to readLine

Tags: java, serialization, io

I am reading a file which contain many serialized objects.
I want to deserialize them back and realized that we cannot use `readObject` like `readLine` ie

```
while (ois.readObject != null) {

}
```

would throw an exception. We also dont have `hasNext` and `next` sort of mechanism in place from my knowledge.

How is the problem of reading object fixed in real world ?

Answer (score 2):

Catch EOFException, and close and break when you get it.

readObject() only returns null if you wrote a null, and that doesn't have to imply the end of the stream.

Comment: Is this commonly seen practice ? or a necessary hack ?

Comment: Unless you can constrain or redefine what's written to the stream, it's the only solution. Certainly *not* a 'hack'. Rather, it's defined behaviour, and it is shared with all the other readXXX() methods other than readLine().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to load Person objects, you could try something like:

```
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList();
        while (true) {
            try {
                persons.add((Person) ois.readObject());
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Or instead of serializing the individual object, you could add your objects to an array or arraylist and serialize the list object. Then you can easily deserialize the list object and you won't have to deal with `EOFException`. See the example in [John Purcell's serialization tutorial](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java-video/serializing-multiple.html).

Comment: Or you can put the loop inside the `try`. That way you avoid the `break`. In your previous code it would also have avoided a second level of `try/catch`.